# Printing integer to textfield area

Tags: java, jframe

[image]

Im having a trouble in java. Im creating a HRRN scheduling. I want to print the integer that I input into a textfield area. Please help me to solve this problem. Thankyou!

```
 private void AWTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    int firstprocess=1;

    if (bt1.getText().equals("")){
    double tempbt1 = Double.parseDouble(bt1.getText());


    awttotalprocess = (firstprocess + (tempbt1));
    AWTCLICK = 0;
    jtf_awt.setText(String.valueOf(awttotalprocess+"ms"));
    }
```

I want to print the awttotalprocess into jtf_awt.

Answer (score 1):

Bracketing issue:

```
jtf_awt.setText(String.valueOf(awttotalprocess)+"ms");
```

Comment: Still not printing I attached the screenshot thankyou!

Comment: Please post complete code.  A screenshot doesn't tell me what I'm looking at.

Comment: This is my full code.
 */
public class HRRN extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double awttotalprocess;
      float AWTCLICK = 0;
 public HRRN() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void AWTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    int firstprocess=1;
    if (bt1.getText().equals("")){
    double tempbt1 = Double.parseDouble(bt1.getText());
    awttotalprocess = (firstprocess + (tempbt1));
    AWTCLICK = 0;
    jtf_awt.setText(String.valueOf(awttotalprocess)+"ms");
    }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Many classes come with what's called a `.toString()` method that prints a pre-specified output when joined with a string. You can concatenate or join a string and a variable -in this case an integer- like this:

```
int i = 50;
String join() {
  return "I'm a string, next is a number: " + 50;
}
```

Keep in mind that int and Integer are different in that the first is a primitive data type, and the second is the object. This isn't an issue for you in this code but in the future if you try to concatenate a string with an object it may end up printing out the memory address as written in the `.toString()` default method and would require you to `@override` the method to specify your own string output. The primitive data types are "easier" to combine and don't require such `.toString()` overriding or `.valueOf()` shenanigans.

Comment: So how will I insert that in textfield? Thankyou!

Comment: jtf_awt.setText("" + awttotalprocess + "milliseconds"); don't forget the "" + in front as that tells the compiler that you want to join a string with a number, not the other way around as that would lead to an error.

Comment: @SimonDeWolf oops, you were right. I've always done it that way for readability.